# C# Refresh DataSet When Value Changed

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to make a responsive DataGridView table but I'm having some difficulties when updating the value of the field.
If I edit the field, leave it out and press on a refresh button - all works out.
If I use one of the triggers like `CellValueChanged` or `CellEndEdit' I get an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.


private void Sync()
{
SqlCommandBuilder cmdr = new SqlCommandBuilder(prekes);
prekes.Update(d.Tables["Prekes"]);
Refresh();
}

private void Refresh()
{
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
d = new DataSet();
prekes.Fill(d, "Prekes");
dataGridView1.DataSource = d.Tables[0];
}
```

dataGridView1.DataSource = d.Tables[0]; is where I get the error..

Please note that I'm getting that error only when I click around, few first times it works just fine. Should I try to catch and exception or something when that happens and ignore it? Or should I use another trigger not CellEndEdit ?

Comment: Why do work with a dataset? A DataTable should be sufficient here. Load the data into the DataTable, change the data and finally call GetChanges() on the DataTable and Update with a DataAdapter. Regards

Comment: You are clearing the DataSet with d = new DataSet() so the next fill statement is null giving you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code snippet in your refresh method

```
prekes.Clear();//dataset.clear
    dataAdaoter.Fill(prekes);//DataAdapter.Fill
```

Comment: Looks like it's working. That's what caused the error it seems. I'll mark this as answered once it let's me. Thanks!